# Use of "is" and "are" when referring to a singular noun or changing the grammatical number

Tags: verb-agreement

I have seen the question [Proper usage of “is” and “are” when specifying multiple nouns](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/128832/proper-usage-of-is-and-are-when-specifying-multiple-nouns), but it is a different questions than what I am asking.

I have two examples (both from songs) of "is" being used that doesn't quite sound right when sung out loud.  I would like to know if these songs are correct in their grammar, or not.

The first is the song "Are You Not Entertained?" by A Broken Silence.  The line is question is:

> Are you not entertained?  Of course you *is*.

And the second song is "I Am Not Done" by Rob Bailey and the Hustle Standard.  The line in question is:

> This is not the pain talking, this *is* called facts.

I know these are specific examples, but they are pretty unique and I couldn't figure this out on my own.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Lyrics from popular songs often use non-standard dialect variants. So they frequently sound different from textbook English. This is normal. English has a **lot** of non-standard dialects, and that's where popular music mostly comes from.

Comment: Good to know.  Why do you specifically say "popular" songs, rather than just songs?  And even knowing that, what would be the textbook way to say the lines in question?

Comment: Of course you *are*. *These are* called facts.

Comment: FWIW, this happens a lot in English particularly with regards to "There is…" and “There are…”. Here is some information on that: <http://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/oddness-when-you-start-a-sentence-with-there-is>.

Answer (score 3):

Both lyrics correctly feature *intentionally* incorrect grammar,  also known as:

> **Enallage** \E*nal"la*ge, n. [L., fr. Gr. ? an exchange, fr. ? to
> exchange; ? in + ? to change.] (Gram.)
> A substitution, as of one part of speech for another, of one
> gender, number, case, person, tense, mode, or voice, of the
> same word, for another.
> [1913 Webster]

Pop songs lyricists have often employed enallage for memorable contrasts, e.g.: *Louis Jordan's* [Is You Is or Is You Ain't My Baby](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Is_You_Is_or_Is_You_Ain%27t_My_Baby), *the Rolling Stone's* [(I Can't Get No) Satisfaction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/(I_Can%27t_Get_No)_Satisfaction), *Frank Zappa's* [You Are What You Is](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_Are_What_You_Is_(song)), *etc.*

---

When used well *Enallage* lends a certain emphasis; it increases the author, poet, or composer's set of available expressive rhymes, meters, alliterations, euphonies, and dissonances; the reader or listener receiving more variety finds themselves less prone to easily guess what comes next.

The price of enallage is loss of formality, and lack of clarity if used badly.   Enallage is not useful in most kinds of legal documents or most formal instructions, excepting whenever and wherever it becomes important to use the fewest number of words, syllables, or letters possible.  Enallage is useful for speakers that wish to quickly warn (or threaten) others about an unpredictable potentially dangerous situation.